# Setting and updating form inputs with firebase database and react hooks

Tags: reactjs, forms, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

In my app I have profile section with a form. When the component mounts I want to fetch user data from firebase, and display it in the form, with the current values of the user profile. Either using the "value" prop or the "placeholder" prop.

When the user makes changes in the form inputs and submit the changes, I want the database to update and the form to update with the new data.

Currently I can make the database value appear in the form input field, or I can make the form input field empty, but update the database. But not both.
The following code makes the database data render in the form input, but it cant be changed.

I know it could be something with the second useEffect() and the getUserData() function, that I cant seem to figure out.

```
const UserEdit = (props) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] =  useState('');
    const [forening, setForening] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        firebase_app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setCurrentUser);
    }, [])

    const getUserData =  async () => {
        await dbRef.ref('/' + currentUser.uid + '/profil/' ).once('value', snapshot => {
        const value =  snapshot.val();
        setForening(value)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getUserData()
    },[] )

    const handleInput = (event) => {
        setForening(event.target.value) 
        
    }

    const updateUserData = () => {
        dbRef.ref('/' + currentUser.uid + '/profil/' ).set({foreningsnavn: forening}, function(error)  {
            if(error) {
                console.log("update failed")
            } else {
                alert(forening)  
            }
        })
    }

    const handleClick = () => {
        updateUserData()
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="card-body">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-5">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label className="form-label">{Forening}</label>
                            <input className="form-control" type="text"  value={forening} onChange={handleInput}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second useEffect will run only one time because the second argument array [] of dependencies is empty:

```
useEffect(() => {
        getUserData()
    },[] )
```

You can add foreign dependency to make useEffect run with input change

```
useEffect(() => {
        getUserData()
    },[foreign] )
```

or you can use polling to sync database state